# Javascript only applying to the first record got by PHP from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

That's a PHP code to display records from database and working, then added a JS code for more styling, but the code is only applied for the first record, the others not.

Any solution for that issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
  $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM listtest";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($selectSQL);
  $stmt->execute();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<img id='slideimg' src='{$row['Image']}'>
          <script>
            function ImgWH() {
              var mImg = document.getElementById('slideimg');
              var mWidth = mImg.clientWidth;
              var mHeight = mImg.clientHeight;
              document.getElementById('slideinfo').style.width = mWidth + 'px';
            }
            ImgWH();
            </script>
            <div id='slideinfo'>
              <p id='slideinfop1'>{$row['Name']}</p>
            </div>";                              
  }
?>
```

Comment: ids in html are unique (slideimg), try using class or create dynamic ids

Comment: i tried to use getElementsByClassName but not worked. How to create a dynamic id?

Comment: here is an example :

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
echo '<div id="'.$i.'">stuff</div>
}

Comment: why, just why would you think it a good idea to declare and redeclare a function in a loop? ID attributes must be unique...

Comment: which HTML element has the ID `slideimgm`? Is that supposed to be `slideimg`??

Comment: yes i forgot to edit it, and i declared the function in the loop i supposed the js code would be applied to every record

Answer (score 0):

Function names cannot be re-declared in the same scope. In this instance you might be better using a single listener to process all the images - remove ID attributes or change them to classNames. The following is untested but might give an idea how to proceed.
The idea here was to use one of the `sibling` selectors that are available - notably `nextElementSibling` to find a reference to the DIV immediately following the `img`

```
<?php

    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM listtest";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($selectSQL);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "
            <img class='slideimg' src='{$row['Image']}' />
            <div class='slideinfo'>
                <p>{$row['Name']}</p>
            </div>";
    }
?>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('img.slideimg').forEach( img => {
        let div=img.nextElementSibling;
            div.style.width=img.clientWidth+'px';
    });
</script>
```